# Using pointers as parameter in method call in Java

Tags: java, pointers, methods, parameters, identifier

I have the following problem:

When using a pointer as parameter in a method call I get the "error: identifier expected" error.

This is my code:

```
class Data {
    Person a = new Person("John");
    Person b = new Person("Mary");

    a.willHug(b);       // Gets error: <identifier> at this line
}

class Person {
    private String name;
    private Person hugs;

    Person(String n){
        this.name = n;
    }

    public void willHug(Person p) {
        hugs = p;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shoul put this code inside of a method in order to execute it:

For instance, the main method:

```
class Data {

    public static void main(String args[]){
         Person a = new Person("John");
         Person b = new Person("Mary");

         a.willHug(b);       // Gets error: <identifier> at this line

    }
}
```

I think you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) question of SO in order to understand better how parameters are passed in Java.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I had a third class with the main method. By symply creating an object of the Data class and calling the method in the main method, the problem was solved.

Thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to surround the operation on `a` with a method, either a class method, a `main()` method, or perhaps even a constructor:

```
class Data {
    Person a = new Person("John");
    Person b = new Person("Mary");

    public Data() {
        a.willHug(b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your code in a main method:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    Person a = new Person("John");
    Person b = new Person("Mary");

    a.willHug(b);
}
```

Also in Java we don't call these pointers they are just variables. A variable has a reference to a particular object instance or primitive value.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a method within the Data class definition?  This is not correct, you either need a 'main' to do that, or place that in another method.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a method there (I introduced a method named foo()) :

```
class Data {
    Person a = new Person("John");
    Person b = new Person("Mary");

    public void foo() {
        a.willHug(b);       // Gets error: <identifier> at this line
    }
}

class Person {
    private String name;
    private Person hugs;

    Person(String n){
        this.name = n;
    }

    public void willHug(Person p) {
        hugs = p;
    }    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't because you use a pointer (called reference in Java) but because this line:

a.willHug(b);

is outside of any method. You can have only declaration or initialization block ({}) in that place.